# Python, How do I convert a text file containing a string into a list, so that I can then calculate the mean and variance of those numbers

Tags: python

I have a text file containing a string:
21.8
18.1
19
23
26
17.8

How would I convert this into a list so that I could then use it to calculate the mean?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read a file line by line into a list with Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277503/how-to-read-a-file-line-by-line-into-a-list-with-python)

Comment: In general when asking on SO you should show that you've tried something already. Please keep that in mind in the future.

Answer (score 0):

To first get the contents of the file you would do:

```
with open("filename.txt", "r") as infile:
    data = infile.read()
```

Now, to get a list from a string you want to use the `.split()` method, so you do:

```
l = data.split()
```

Now `l` is a list of strings. To convert it into a list of numbers you could use list comprehensions, and do:

```
l = [float(num) for num in l]
```

This gives you a list `l` of the numbers in the file.
Hope it helped!

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
 l = [float(v) for v in open(filename).readline().split()]
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution using [numpy.mean](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.mean.html#numpy.mean) and [numpy.var](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.var.html#numpy.var) functions:

```
import numpy as np

# 21.8 18.1 19 23 26 17.8
with open('numbers.txt', 'r') as fh:
    numbers = fh.read().split(' ')
    np_arr = np.array(numbers).astype(np.float)
    avg = np.mean(np_arr)
    variance = np.var(np_arr)

print('avg: {:.2f}, variance: {:.2f}'.format(avg, variance))
```

The output:

```
avg: 20.95, variance: 8.71
```